# What does it mean to observe an event with no qualifiers if all events have @Any as a qualifier?

Tags: cdi

The [CDI specification](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/3.0/jakarta-cdi-spec-3.0.html#event_types_and_qualifier_types) says, in [section 10.1](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/3.0/jakarta-cdi-spec-3.0.html#event_types_and_qualifier_types):

> Every event [object] has the qualifier `@jakarta.enterprise.inject.Any`, even if it does not explicitly declare this qualifier.

(Terminology is important; this is in a part of the spec talking about event *objects*, i.e. the things you fire, i.e. payloads, that can be observed by observer methods, *not* the poorly-named `Event` object, which you use to fire event objects.)

Then in [section 10.4.1](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/3.0/jakarta-cdi-spec-3.0.html#observer_method_event_parameter), talking about observer methods and their parameters, it says:

> If the event parameter [of an observer method] does not explicitly declare any qualifier, the observer method observes events with no qualifier.

(This is probably distinguishing this from "ordinary" injection where if you don't put a qualifier on your injection point you get `@Default` by default; in this case the spec is saying no analogous default applies.)

Leaving aside how observer resolution works (covered in [section 10.3](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/3.0/jakarta-cdi-spec-3.0.html#observer_resolution)), is there any state of affairs where an event object could have no qualifiers, given [section 10.1](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/3.0/jakarta-cdi-spec-3.0.html#event_types_and_qualifier_types)?  Or is [section 10.4.1](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/3.0/jakarta-cdi-spec-3.0.html#observer_method_event_parameter) just a statement about what qualifiers are automatically applied to the method parameter (namely none)?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can interpret the specification, the part from section 10.4.1

> If the event parameter [of an observer method] does not explicitly
> declare any qualifier, the observer method observes events with no
> qualifier.

Makes the third bullet point from section 10.3 come into effect:

> if [...] The observer method has no event qualifiers [...]

Therefore, the observer method received the event with the @Any qualifier.

Answer (score 0):

> Every event [object] has the qualifier @jakarta.enterprise.inject.Any, even if it does not explicitly declare this qualifier.

This statement is basically a prepping ground for observer resolution ([10.3](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/3.0/jakarta-cdi-spec-3.0.html#observer_resolution)) and is needed in order for the 10.4.1 statement you quoted to work.

Under the hood, there are always qualifiers - at least `@Any` and this is also an  explanation as to why your observer for, say, `String` type and with "no qualifier" (from user code view) gets notified for every single event of type `String` regardless the event payload qualifiers.

The spec wordings you quoted are basically a scaffolding allowing CDI to express what happens when user doesn't specify qualifiers all the while actually adding them in the background when appropriate and then performing resolution.

To see what I mean, try experimenting with these observers:

```
    public void observe(@Observes String payload) {
        observerTriggered++; // assuming you are counting the triggers...
    }

    public void observe2(@Observes @Any String payload) {
        observerTriggered2++;
    }

    public void observe3(@Observes @Default String payload) {
        observerTriggered3++;
    }

    public void observe4(@Observes @DummyQualifier("foo") String payload) {
        observerTriggered4++;
    }
```

And fire the following events and watch which observers get triggered:

```
        Event<Object> event = // retrieve the event object somehow
        event.select(String.class).fire("irrelevantPayload");
        event.select(String.class, Any.Literal.INSTANCE).fire("irrelevantPayload");
        event.select(String.class, Default.Literal.INSTANCE).fire("irrelevantPayload");
        event.select(String.class, new DummyQualifier.Literal("foo")).fire("irrelevantPayload");
```

Comment: So shouldn't "If the event parameter [of an observer method] does not explicitly declare any qualifier, the observer method observes events <strike>with no qualifier</strike>" be "If the event parameter [of an observer method] does not explicitly declare any qualifier, the observer method observes events **with only the `@Any` qualifier**", given that "every event has the qualifier `@jakarta.enterprise.inject.Any`, even if it does not explicitly declare this qualifier"?

Comment: More like "If the event parameter [of an observer method] does not explicitly declare any qualifier, the observer method observes behaves **as if it had @Any qualifier**". Because the observer is notified if it has a _subset_ of qualifiers of the event. E.g. it will be notified not only for `@Any` but also for events with same type and more qualifiers. But the above wording I gave is even more confusing for users so that's (I guess) why spec went with talking about "no qualifiers" instead of forcing users to always keep in mind what qualifiers are/aren't added.

Comment: BTW if you want to debug the observer resolution in Weld, you can take a look at [`TypesafeObserverResolver`](https://github.com/weld/core/blob/master/impl/src/main/java/org/jboss/weld/resolution/TypeSafeObserverResolver.java#L69). The answers above are from the top of my head but I am pretty confident that's the way it should work :)

Comment: Yeah; I understand how it works, but the specification seems sloppy here; that's all.